# This Argument typr 'File' cant be assigned in this paameter type File

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPTat.png)

while Image picker, I couldn't solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have imported some unrelated File types from other libraries.
To fix this, remove the imports:

```
C:\Users\91908\Downloads\ flutter_windows 3.3.9-stable\flutter\bin\cache lpkg \sky_engine\lib\html html_dart2js.dart
C: Users\91908\Downloads\flutter windows_3.3.9-stable\flutter\bin|cache\pkg\sky_engine Vib\io\file.dart
```

Now click on the `imageFile` variable and import the appropriate class.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because You are importing two libraries having property named as File.
Just import "Dart io" which is responsible for image Files.

```
import 'dart:io';
```

It is defined at (C: Users\91908\Downloads\flutter windows_3.3.9-stable\flutter\bin|cache\pkg\sky_engine Vib\io\file.dart) in your PC.

And remove the other library which is causing issue.
In your case probably it is

```
html_dart2js;
```

It is defined at (C:\Users\91908\Downloads\ flutter_windows 3.3.9-stable\flutter\bin\cache lpkg \sky_engine\lib\html html_dart2js.dart) in your PC.